# Output php multidimensional array to html list

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I have the following array set in a php script and i am trying to get it to output as per the code below. I have tried looping but i am at a loss as to how i get it to show the sub arrays. I am hoping someone can help me.

**PHP Array**

```
$fruits = array();
$fruits[] = array('type' => 'Banana', 'code' => 'ban00');
$fruits[] = array('type' => 'Grape', 'code' => 'grp01');
$fruits[] = array('type' => 'Apple', 'code' => 'apl00',
               array('subtype' => 'Green', 'code' => 'apl00gr'),
               array('subtype' => 'Red', 'code' => 'apl00r')
            );
$fruits[] = array('type' => 'Lemon', 'code' => 'lem00');
```

**Desired Output**

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Banana"> Banana</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Grape"> Grape</li>
    <li>Apple
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Green"> Green</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Red"> Red</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Lemon"> Lemon</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have any code example that you have tried? can you even get a single dimension array outputted? We could move on easier if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursive function. Note that this is a example and not a direct solution, as we are here to learn and not to get the job done - change this as needed.

```
function renderList(array $data) {
   $html = '<ul>';
   foreach ($data as $item) {
      $html .= '<li>';
      foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
         if (is_array($value)) {
             $html .= renderList($value);
         } else {
             $html .= $value;
         }
      }
      $html .= '</li>';
   }
   $html .= '</ul>';
   return $html;
}

$data = array();
$data[] = array('A');
$data[] = array('B', array(array('C')));
$data[] = array('D');

echo renderList($data);
```

The output of this will be:

- A
- B

  - C
- D

Or in html form:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B
        <ul>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.I have not tried to code you for you, just tried to give you an idea.I hope you can proceed.

```
echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $fruits as $fruit){
    echo  '<li>' . $fruit . '</li>';
        if( is_array($fruit) ){
             echo  '<ul>';
             foreach( $fruit as $fr ){
                 echo '<li>' . $fr . '</li>';
             }
           echo '</ul>';
    }
        }echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$fruits = array();
$fruits[] = array(
    'type' => 'Banana',
    'code' => 'ban00'
);
$fruits[] = array(
    'type' => 'Grape',
    'code' => 'grp01'
);
$fruits[] = array(
    'type' => 'Apple',
    'code' => 'apl00',
    array(
        'subtype' => 'Green',
        'code' => 'apl00gr'),
    array(
        'subtype' => 'Red',
        'code' => 'apl00r'
    )
);
$fruits[] = array(
    'type' => 'Lemon',
    'code' => 'lem00'
);

iterate($fruits, 'type');

function iterate($fruits, $index)
{
    foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
        echo "<ul>";
        display($fruit, $index);
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

function display($data, $index)
{
    echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="' . $data[$index] . '">' . $data[$index];
    if (!empty($data[0]) && is_array($data[0])) {
        $newSubArray = $data;
        unset($newSubArray['type']);
        unset($newSubArray['code']);
        iterate($newSubArray, 'subtype');
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
```